# The Windows Firewall won’t run on startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall, autorun

For some reason, the Windows (7) Firewall will not run on startup. When the security center starts, it reports that the firewall is not running and prompts me to start it. I click the flag to start it and the Windows Firewall runs without issue.

Why do I have to manually start the Windows Firewall? Why won’t it run on it’s own? (Yes, it *is* set to `Automatic` startup.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Windows 7 Firewall requires the *DHCP* service to be set to `Automatic` startup in order for the firewall to auto-run.

I use a static IP so I have it set to `Manual`, but even that is insufficient. To get the firewall to automatically start, the *DHCP* service **must** be set to `Automatic` (for some reason).

Comment: (I suppose I could create a delayed auto-run command to stop the DHCP service after the firewall has started, but frankly *why should I have to‽*)

Answer (score 1):

I don't run windows as a daily driver but I know what it is
try to solve with this  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943996/en-us
if not Win + R -> services.msc
find windows firewall service and choose props -> general tab -> startup type -> automatic
then stop service -> start service -> Ok, and I think, reboot
something like this
good luck

Comment: Did you read the answer I already? I had already figured it out, explained the reason for the problem, and posted it in case other people have the same issue.